# Change Generic Handler window's title during PDF viewing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generic-handler

I'm trying to open PDF file in browser using Generic Handler (ASP.NET MVC).
When I open it, window title is the name of this Handler, written in its class.
If I try to download PDF using its own download button, the type of downloading file is PDF and name - file's name; I have added headers in Handler's script ("Content-Type" and "Content-Disposition": "filename=\"fileName.pdf\"").

I tried to write `context.Response.AddHeader("Title", "fileName.pdf");`, but it does not work too.

How can I change window title/name, viewing PDF using Generic Handler?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Tab/window title is for pdf files is taken from 'title' property of pdf file, You may find some hint [here](https://support.mozilla.org/pl/questions/1111417)